# Custom header not found in HttpContext.Current.Request.Header array

Tags: c#, httpcontext

I add a custom header to each of my calls made from an Angular service to pass a system Id to my application

```
$http.defaults.headers.common["SystemId"] = "1";
```

When using Fiddler I can see that the custom header is added

[image]

[image]

On the server side I'm trying to retrieve this header from a user defined C# class by doing the following

```
if (HttpContext.Current != null)
{
    systemIdHeader = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["SystemId"];                                
}
```

The `HttpContext.Current` object is set but the Headers array is empty. Is there any reason why this header will go missing?

Comment: Is whole collection empty or maybe `SystemId` is missing?

Comment: The entire collection is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the problem. I'm posting to an oAuth token endpoint which is making use of the `OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext`, so I had to use

```
_oAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext.Request.Headers["SystemId"];
```

instead of

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["SystemId"];
```